# Symfony 3.0: Reuse entity in repository

Tags: php, symfony

On my Symfony 3.0 project I have a Entity named `ImageGroups` and a repository I made `ImageGroupsRepository` that Use `ImageGroups` entity. I also made an `Images` entity with a `ImagesRepository`

In `ImageGroupsRepository` I have a method named `getUserImageGroups` and on `ImagesRepository` I have a method named `add`.

What I want to ask is How to use the `getUserImageGroups` method from `ImageGroupsRepository` into `add` from `ImagesRepository`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your repository, you can get the entity manager with `$this->getEntityManager()`, this allow to call `getRepository()` in order to get another repository:

```
class ImagesRepository extends EntityRepository
{
    public function add()
    {
        $em = $this->getEntityManager();

        $imagesGroups = $em
            ->getRepository('AcmeBundle:ImageGroups')
            ->getUserImageGroups();

        // …
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

The answer given by A.L is correct, I just wanted to offer an alternative method to access the entity manager without having to call the function again, via `$this->_em`:

```
class ImagesRepository extends EntityRepository
{
    public function add()
    {
        $imagesGroups = $this->_em
            ->getRepository('AcmeBundle:ImageGroups')
            ->getUserImageGroups();

        // …
    }
}
```

If you look at the [documentation for EntityRepository](https://github.com/doctrine/doctrine2/blob/2.5/lib/Doctrine/ORM/EntityRepository.php#L276) you'll see that the `getEntityManager()` function simply returns the protected `$_em` member of the `EntityRepository` class.